# Error in response from PUT method using compression

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using gzip compression in my .net core api. Responses from HTTP GET methods are all ok. When this method is a HTTP Put (example) the response body is corrupted. My put method response is the same data from request with additional information.
Have a additional configuration for this case?

This is my configuration:

```
services.AddResponseCompression(opt =>
{
    opt.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    opt.EnableForHttps = true;
});
services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(opt => opt.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);
```

Comment: Could you please show you put method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all interested.
I have make a extensive debugging and found the problem: some classes with a circular reference caused serialization error.